# Redirect users after login

Tags: users, redirect

I search my question but all users that said paste custom code in **functions.php**
 
I have two Page Templates for login with this code:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'echo'           => true,
    'remember'       => true,
    'redirect'       => 'mysite.com',
    'form_id'        => 'loginform',
    'id_username'    => 'user_login',
    'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
    'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
    'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
    'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
    'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
    'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
    'label_log_in'   => __( 'Log In' ),
    'value_username' => '',
    'value_remember' => false
);
wp_login_form( $args ); ?>
```

but when users click on button redirect to /wp-admin.
I need two login page with two different redirect

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Laxmana i need a login form in my page when user login from this page redirect to mysite.com not mysite.com/wp-admin

Comment: If you read at the docs of [`wp_login_form`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form) it says that the redirect url must be absolute meaning `http://example.org`

Comment: @Laxmana in first answer say docs of wp_login_form but i said don't work and don't redirect

Comment: Use `home_url()` instead of `site_url()`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code with little modification in 2 Page Templates and it seems to be working. The only change I did was in the `redirect` parameter. Below is the updated code with the `redirect` parameter. You need to provide absolute path in `redirect` parameter. Please check the function reference of `wp_login_form` on following link. `https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form`

```
$args = array(
    'echo'           => true,
    'remember'       => true,
    'redirect'       => site_url( '/page-slug'),
    'form_id'        => 'loginform',
    'id_username'    => 'user_login',
    'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
    'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
    'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
    'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
    'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
    'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
    'label_log_in'   => __( 'Log In' ),
    'value_username' => '',
    'value_remember' => false
);
wp_login_form( $args );
```

In the above code, user will be redirected to http://domain_name/page-slug page after login.

Comment: thanks but don't work. user will be redirected to /wp-admin/profile.php!

Comment: @Laxmana use 'home_url()' but don't work

Comment: @Alireza - It might be possible that there is some filter like login_redirect or hook like wp_login is used in your setup which is causing the issue.